# custom URL and SSL to subsite

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, url, ssl

For starters, I just had SharePoint administration tacked on to my other duties and I don't know a lot about it yet. So bear with me.

I want to point a url to a subsite, eg. clientportal.company.com to sharepoint.company.com/client/portal/page.aspx, what are my options?

I also need to apply an SSL cert to the subsite...

I'm on a time crunch that I'm sweating a bit so hopefully I can get pointed in the right direction.

I'm exploring the possibility of migrating the subsite to its own web application, and then using AAM but I'm concerned with library and form data connections.

Comment: You can do a redirect at clientportal.company.com/index.html to toss the user over to sharepoint.company.com/client/portal/page.aspx.

There are other ways to do it like subdomains pointing at virtual paths but they slaughter URLs

Comment: that's a solution I considered, and I might end up doing that way, however I think that moving the subsite to host-named site collection might be a better option. I'm just concerned about the existing pages and forms.